# How to optimize the rendering performance of long text with automatic line wraps in uwp?

Tags: c#, uwp

This problem statement was translated by a translation program, so please forgive me if it doesn't make sense.
I'm creating a `txt` file reader program in `uwp` and `c#`. I tried using `ScrollViewer` and `TextBlock` to display a long string (`txt` file) of several megabytes long on the page, but rendering (setting `TextBlock.Text`) would jam the `UI`. I thought I might have to use `UI` virtualization techniques if I wanted to display such a large string, but all the articles I could find on the web about `uwp` `UI` virtualization only worked for `ItemsControl` and its derived classes. However, when I try to use `ItemsControl`, binding its `ItemsSource` property to a string will split my string into lines, character by character, and I need to display the string in a continuous and automatic line feed. How exactly do I display this `txt` file on the page?
Thanks.

Comment: A common way to avoid the effect is to put the whole text into several parts. You could show the first part first and then add the next parts when users read to the end of the first part.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to put the whole text into several parts. Then only show the first part
in the textblock and then add the next parts when users read to the end of the first part.